# Laravel blade check empty foreach

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I want to check if my foreach is empty so the basic html markup isn't displayed with no results inside. I'm trying to wrap it in an if statement and then if it is empty do nothing else loop the foreach.

```
@if ($status->replies === '')

@elseif
<div class="media-body reply-body">
    @foreach ($status->replies as $reply)
        <p>{{ $reply->body }}</p>
    @endforeach
</div>
@endif

@if (!(empty($status->replies))
<div class="media-body reply-body">
    @foreach ($status->replies as $reply)
        <div class="media">
            <a class="pull-left" href="{{ route('profile.index', ['username' => $reply->user->username]) }}">
                <img class="media-object" alt="{{ $reply->user->getNameOrUsername() }}" src="{{ $reply->user->getAvatarUrl() }}">
            </a>
            <div class="media-body">
                <h5 class="media-heading"><a href="{{ route('profile.index', ['username' => $reply->user->username]) }}">{{ $reply->user->getNameOrUsername() }}</a></h5>
                <p>{{ $reply->body }}</p>
                <ul class="list-inline list-replies">
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ route('status.like', ['statusId' => $reply->id]) }}"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></a>
                    {{ $reply->likes->count() }} {{ str_plural('like', $reply->likes->count()) }}</li>
                    <li>{{ $reply->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <hr>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
@endif
```

Comment: If `$status->replies` is empty, why not test for that using [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)?... `@if (empty($status->replies))` rather than assuming that if it's empty it will be a string?

Answer (score 299, accepted):

Check the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#control-structures) for the best result:

```
@forelse($status->replies as $reply)
    <p>{{ $reply->body }}</p>
@empty
    <p>No replies</p>
@endforelse
```

Comment: It might be old, but jeez, I now have so much code to rewrite now! I had no idea this existed!

Comment: Golden answer to this guy!

Comment: btw, this doesn't work for rendering tables, because you'll get a table without rows (or with single row) with a para inside - while what you need is no table at all plus a para

Comment: Still usefull to me.

Answer (score 58):

I think you are trying to check whether the array is empty or not.You can do like this :

```
@if(!$result->isEmpty())
     // $result is not empty
@else
    // $result is empty
@endif
```

**Reference** [isEmpty()](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_isEmpty)

Comment: not always one may use `@forelse` (e.g for rendering not-empty tables). one may not also use `@empty` (nor even `empty($collection)`!) with empty collections. the solution suggested by you remains the last resort! thx!

Answer (score 11):

You should use empty()

```
@if (!empty($status->replies)) 

<div class="media-body reply-body">
    @foreach ($status->replies as $reply)
        <p>{{ $reply->body }}</p>
    @endforeach
</div>

@endif
```

You can use count, but if the array is larger it takes longer, if you only need to know if its empty, empty is the better one to use.

Comment: Thanks for your answer using this method I get the following error - 
`syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '('`

Comment: updated first post with full code, when I remove the if statement we just added the page loads find with no errors :S

Comment: If you remove everything from inside your foreach so you still get the error?

Comment: If `$status` is a collection, checking with `empty()` will not work, it will always return true. You must use one of `$status->isEmpty()`, `$status->count()`, or `count($status)`.

Answer (score 6):

It's an array, so `==== ''` won't work (the === means it has to be an empty string.)

Use [count()](http://php.net/count]) to identify the array has any elements (count returns a number, 1 or greater will evaluate to true, 0 = false.)

```
@if (count($status->replies) > 0)
 // your HTML + foreach loop
@endif
```

Answer (score 5):

> #### Echoing Data If It Exists
>
> Sometimes you may wish to echo a variable, but you aren't sure if the variable has been set. We can express this in verbose PHP code like so:
>
> ```
> {{ isset($name) ? $name : 'Default' }}
> ```
>
> However, instead of writing a ternary statement, Blade provides you with the following convenient short-cut:
>
> ```
> {{ $name or 'Default' }}
> ```
>
> In this example, if the $name variable exists, its value will be displayed. However, if it does not exist, the word Default will be displayed.

From https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#displaying-data

Comment: Now that Laravel requires PHP 7.1, you can use the null coalesce operator:
 
    {{ $name ?? 'Default'}} 

(The "or"-operator is deprecated in Laravel 5.6)

Answer (score 2):

The **modern, easiest and shortest solution in Laravel 9 upwards** would be the `@empty` tag:

```
@empty($data)
    {{ $data }} is empty.
@else
    // Your HTML + foreach for $data
    {{ $data }} is NOT empty.
@endempty
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my best solution if I understood the question well:

Use of `$object->first()` method to run the code inside `if` statement once, that is when on the first loop. The same concept is true with `$object->last()`.

```
    @if($object->first())
        <div class="panel user-list">
          <table id="myCustomTable" class="table table-hover">
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                     <th class="col-email">Email</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
    @endif

    @foreach ($object as $data)
        <tr class="gradeX">
           <td class="col-name"><strong>{{ $data->email }}</strong></td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach

    @if($object->last())
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Using following code, one can first check variable is set or not using @isset of laravel directive and then check that array is blank or not using @unless of laravel directive

```
@if(@isset($names))
    @unless($names)
        Array has no value
    @else
        Array has value

        @foreach($names as $name)
            {{$name}}
        @endforeach

    @endunless
@else
    Not defined
@endif
```