# Laravel 7.7 Display user Post/Products in public profile in single page

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have laravel 7.7 app which contains multiple user and all users have products. Now I want to display a user profile for guest visitor on www.domain.com/company/user-name . All the product that the users has created should be displayed on the same page along with user profile.

All product are being saved with user_id.

My Product Model has:

```
// User relation
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Add\User', 'user_id');
}
```

My User Model has:

```
public function product(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}
```

CompanyController has:

```
public function show($slug)
{
    // Show individual company
    $user = User::where('slug', $slug)->first();
    return view('company.show')->with('user', $user);
}
```

Migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('image');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('text');
        $table->string('price');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

I need help understanding how to grab/display all products of user from user_id in product table in CompanyController. Without using auth.

Comment: shouldn't `Add\User` be `App\User` ?

Comment: Yes. just a typing mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreach like this.

```
foreach ($user->product as $product) {

}
```

In controller. Notice that it's use like `->product` and not like `->product()` And  notise it's more appropriate using `products()` inside Model.

And inside blade you can use. ince you have mentioned table I'm guessing you need to iterate `<td>` s inside blade foreach.

```
@foreach ($user->product as $product)

@endforeach
```

Comment: it's not in <td>. And in controller I added $user->product which is not working.

Comment: error is "Trying to get property 'logo' of non-object"

I have logo in user table.

Comment: The reason may be there are no users in table. Try adding inside forelse instead of foreach. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32652818/laravel-blade-check-empty-foreach#answer-32653175

Comment: Now getting this:
Property [logo] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: Try this answer. Think that is your issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41366092/property-title-does-not-exist-on-this-collection-instance#answer-41366122

Comment: Didn't work. Now Getting:
Trying to get property 'logo' of non-object

Comment: `<div>   
                        @foreach ($collection as $product)
                        
                        <h1>{{ $product->text}}</h1>
                            
                        @endforeach
                    </div>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213737/discussion-between-aruna-perera-and-nargesh-rana).

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

Model user

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Model product

```
public function product(){
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'user_id');
}
```

If not right, put your migrates.